# JavaFX - Dragging nodes + ScrollPane backwards?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application, which have a scrollable area. In that scrollable area, you can add draggable nodes of various Types. You would think that if you drag a node towards an edge, it would scroll in that direction. However, it scrolls in the opposite direction.

Dragging works as such:

```
        myNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t){
                originalX1 = 200;
                originalY1 = 200;
                newX1 = ((WebView)(t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                newY1 = ((WebView)(t.getSource())).getTranslateY();

                System.out.println("(" + newX1 + ", " + newY1 + ")");
        }
    });
    myNode.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t){
                double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - 210;
                double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - 220;
                double newTranslateX = newX + offsetX;
                double newTranslateY = newY + offsetY;

                ((NodeType)(t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                ((NodeType)(t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);

                System.out.println("(" + newTranslateX + ", " + newTranslateY + ")");

        }
    });
```

Comment: do you have a scrollpane in which you drag or is the webview the "scrollable" area?

Comment: Woops, I meant to change that to NodeType. It's various different node types which are draggable within an anchorpane, which is fit to a scrollpane. Thank you for the response, I didn't think I'd get anything. @Kalaschni

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll in a `ScrollPane` you should probably use the `Hvalue` and the `Vvalue` of the ScrollPane.
As an approach, something like this:

```
if (scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth() - t.getSceneX() <= 20) { // Look if the user dragged to the right border
    // Set the horizontal scroll-bar 3% wider
    scrollPane.setHvalue(scrollPane.getHvalue() + 0.03);
} else if (scrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight() - t.getSceneY() <= 20) { // Look if the user dragged to the bottom border 
    // Set the vertical scroll-bar 3% wider
    scrollPane.setVvalue(scrollPane.getVvalue() + 0.03);
}
// @TODO Do this for the top and left border too
```

Happy Coding,
Kalasch